# Cant import from non EcmaScript module in angular

Tags: angular, npm, dependencies, npm-install, ngx-image-cropper

[image]

I am using ngx-image-cropper dependency and I don't know why this error is coming whenever I import it in my app.component.module.ts in angular.

Trying to solve this issue from 3 hours but unable to!!